# Command line: How do you rotate a PDF file 90 degrees?

Tags: command-line, pdf, pdftk, poppler

When I scan documents that are landscape-oriented, the output PDF files are portrait and so all the PDF viewers display the scanned documents in portrait.

**From the command line, how do you rotate a PDF file 90 degrees?**

I tried searching and found a bunch of solutions but I had trouble finding what looked like an authoritative solution[1] that uses a stable and robust Linux/Unix tool.

---

footnote [1]

For example, here is a sampling of some of the haphazard solutions I found:

- "just use Adobe Acrobat Pro to rotate the file and then save the file"
- "use pdfjam"
- "use PDFtk"
- "use ${PROGRAM_NAME} from Poppler"
- "use ImageMagick's convert"
  -- but then all the comments were very negative and stating "the image quality is ruined"
- "open the file in a PDF viewer, then rotate, then print using a PDF printer like cutePDF or PDF printer or etc"
- "use ${PROGRAM_NAME}", then I searched for "${PROGRAM_NAME}" and there is something about "Fedora removed ${PROGRAM_NAME} because of licensing issues"

Comment: There are no "authorative solutions", but you should keep in mind what *method* the various solutions use: Direct manipulation of PDF structure (pdftk, Adobe Acrobat, and other programs), converting to an image and then converting back to a PDF (e.g. Imagemagick's convert, printing using PDF printer etc.). The latter is obviously a bad idea.

Comment: How are those *haphazard solution*? How were you disappointed by each one of them? Did you *actually* try them?

Comment: I've found `qpdf` to work great and be _super fast_. I tested it on Ubuntu 20.04 too. See 1) [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495660/114401), and 2) [my answer, with additional info. and examples](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634882/114401).

Comment: [Best answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634882/409331).

Answer (score 162):

Use PDFtk.

1. For rotating clockwise:

   ```
    pdftk input.pdf cat 1-endeast output output.pdf
   ```
2. For rotating anti-clockwise:

   ```
    pdftk input.pdf cat 1-endwest output output.pdf
   ```

Regarding the installation of PDFtk on Fedora, I found these links:

- [Pdftk substitute for Fedora 21 and 22](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905194722/https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/73364/pdftk-substitute-for-fedora-21-and-22/)
- [Pdftk not available?](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/pdftk-not-available/8062)
- [Install pdftk on Fedora using the Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/install/pdftk/fedora)

Comment: The man page of pdftk states more options for rotating: `The page rotation setting can cause pdftk to rotate pages and documents. Each option sets the page rotation as follows (in degrees): north: 0, east: 90, south: 180, west: 270, left: -90, right: +90, down: +180. left, right, and down make relative adjustments to a page's rotation.`

Comment: Output is rotated but still scaled small enough to fit the original orientation. Not helpful.

Comment: @JohnMudd What do you mean by "scaled small enough to fit the original orientation" ? I suppose you now have a problem with the PDF viewer, not with the rotation of pages.

Comment: My original PDF was a letter size page rotated 90 degrees so page height was reduced from 11" to 8.5". Didn't change after correcting rotation. Found this  to be true with many online tools. Might not be a problem with conversion after all. I found a scaling option while viewing/printing rotated PDF and that fixed it. Sorry, I was so frustrated at that point that I just printed and moved on and didn't note the exact steps I took.

Comment: +1 for sharing *pdftk* solution. https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/

Comment: `pdftk` is removed in Ubuntu 18.04 and above. Ubuntu itself suggests to install a snap, which works only in simple situations (it did not find my files, perhaps because they were outside of my home directory ?). I moved to `pdfjam ... --angle 270...`.

Comment: pdftk still available in CentOS7.9, nice quality.

Comment: For rotating 180 degrees:  `pdftk input.pdf 1-endsouth output output.pdf`

Comment: Also works under Windows, using WSL. Move to the right folder and do your thing: `cd /mnt/c/Users/John/Downloads/`

Answer (score 102):

I just stumbled upon this thread and saw that there is no good solution mentioned yet. I found that (at least on Debian and Ubuntu) pdfjam comes with the following commands:

```
pdf90 input.pdf
pdf180 input.pdf
pdf270 input.pdf
```

I think that is the easiest and fastest approach. These are scripts using the pdfjam command properly. Btw. the pdfjam is a virtual package that comes with `texlive-extra-utils`

**UPDATE**

The above commands were dropped from `pdfjam` since version 3.02, and are [now available](https://github.com/DavidFirth/pdfjam-extras) (but unmaintained) in the package `pdfjam-extras`. The direct commands that work with `pdfjam` (as mentioned in the comments) are respectively:

```
pdfjam --landscape --angle 90 input.pdf
pdfjam --angle 180 input.pdf
pdfjam --landscape --angle 270 input.pdf
```

Comment: Looks like 90 goes counterclockwise and 270 goes clockwise - perhaps you should mention that.

Comment: pdf90 is indeed a thin wrapper. Yet it forces a suffix convention. So I used pdfjam directly: `pdfjam --outfile myoutputfile.pdf --angle 270 --fitpaper true --rotateoversize true myinputfile.pdf`

Comment: you can also change the suffix using the argument `--suffix desired_suffix`. Default is : `--suffix rotated90` so the output is : `initial_name-rotated90.pdf`

Comment: To rotate 90° clockwise: `pdfjam --landscape --angle -90 input.pdf`. Mind the `-` in `-90`.

Answer (score 89):

In Linux Mint 18.3 (I believe in other Debian derived distributions as well) you have a simple command line tool named [`qpdf`](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf).

You can use: `qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --rotate=[+|-]angle[:page-range]`.

[From the documentation](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

> --rotate=[+|-]angle[:page-range]
>
> Apply rotation to specified pages. The page-range portion of the option value has the same format as page ranges in Section 3.5, “Page Selection Options”. If the page range is omitted, the rotation is applied to all pages. The angle portion of the parameter may be either 90, 180, or 270. If preceded by + or -, the angle is added to or subtracted from the specified pages' original rotations. Otherwise the pages' rotations are set to the exact value. For example, the command `qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --rotate=+90:2,4,6 --rotate=180:7-8` would rotate pages 2, 4, and 6 90 degrees clockwise from their original rotation and force the rotation of pages 7 through 9 to 180 degrees regardless of their original rotation, and the command `qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --rotate=180` would rotate all pages by 180 degrees.

In your case, to rotate all pages in a PDF 90 degrees clockwise, you can do:

```
qpdf --rotate=+90 in.pdf out.pdf
```

Comment: Specifying the page-range seems to be compulsory, at least in my current qpdf version (8.0.2).

Comment: It seems at least not to be the case anymore (9.0.2): `qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --rotate==-90` works well for all pages.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. All others I tried didn't work. pdftk didn't produce any output. pdf90 and friends would require 192MB of space for all texlive-extra-utils stuff. I only had to tweak the command line a bit. As stated above, page is mandatory. I used this: `qpdf input.pdf output.pdf --rotate=90:1`

Comment: Page doesn't seem to be mandatory to me (8.4.2), but I had to put the parameter before input and output: `qpdf --rotate=90 input.pdf output.pdf`. In any case, that's easy to figure out and the package itself is only a few hundred kilobytes, so it's the best option IMO.

Comment: qpdf seems great. It can rotate pages as said in the answer, it can also concat files using the following syntax: `qpdf --collate --empty --pages a.pdf 1-3 back.pdf 1-4 -- c.pdf`. It has no dependency, can be installed using `apt install qpdf` and is really light (takes ~2KB according to apt).

Comment: I just added an answer to provide some more information about how to install and use `qpdf` for rotating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394065/command-line-how-do-you-rotate-a-pdf-file-90-degrees/634882#634882.

Comment: The true answer in 2023

Answer (score 31):

You can use ImageMagick: `display` or `convert` - e.g. to rotate it clockwise use

```
convert -rotate 90 <file>.pdf <rotated-file>.pdf
```

Use -90 for a counterclockwise rotation.

N.B. *Only* use this method when the original image is a bitmap (e.g. produced by scanning). If the original image is not a bitmap, this method will convert it to one and quality will suffer. In the latter case, please use one of the methods in the other answers.

Comment: This will first convert the PDF text to an image, so size will increase and quality will drop (Unless it was already only a scan).

Comment: Yes indeed, that is a useful reminder, but in this case the OP states that he is scanning the documents.

Comment: Result pdf is very low quality.

Comment: This method is good only for scanned originals: they are already bitmaps. For ordinary PDFs, see @aviv's comment above and maybe use the method in the other answer.

Comment: @IvanRomanov [Adding `-quality 100` removes some of the noticeable noise](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493584/convert-images-to-pdf#comment1497989_557975)

Answer (score 24):

### `qpdf` works great and is *super fast*!:

*Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with **qpdf version 8.0.2** (see `qpdf --version`), but I suspect it would work fine on Ubuntu 18.04, 16.04, and 14.04 too, since I've used `qpdf` in other ways on all of those systems as well.*

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qpdf

# Rotate in.pdf +90 deg and save as out.pdf
qpdf --rotate=+90 in.pdf out.pdf

# Rotate in.pdf -90 deg and save as out.pdf
qpdf --rotate=-90 in.pdf out.pdf

# Rotate in.pdf +/-180 deg and save as out.pdf
qpdf --rotate=+180 in.pdf out.pdf
```

The manual pages ([`man qpdf`](https://www.mankier.com/1/qpdf)) show *very* little, but what they do show is *very important*. Here's a key part right at the end of it (emphasis added):

> For a summary of qpdf's options, please run `qpdf --help`.  A **complete manual** can be found in **/usr/share/doc/qpdf/qpdf-manual.html** or **/usr/share/doc/qpdf/qpdf-manual.pdf**.

So, read the full manual which is stored locally on your computer! Here are the links. Copy and paste them into your browser's address bar to open them. You can also view the manual online here: https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/.

1. Local QPDF manual location on Linux:

   1. QPDF User manual in PDF form: **file:///usr/share/doc/qpdf/qpdf-manual.pdf**
   2. QPDF User manual in HTML form: **file:///usr/share/doc/qpdf/qpdf-manual.html**

To see the help options, run `qpdf --help` instead. Or, even better, pipe to `less`:

```bsh
qpdf --help | less -RFX
```

Then you can press `/` and search for `--rotate`. Here's a snippet from the help pages:

> ```bash
> --rotate=[+|-]angle[:page-range]
>                         rotate each specified page 90, 180, or 270 degrees;
>                         rotate all pages if no page range is given
> ```

and:

> The `--rotate` flag can be used to specify pages to rotate pages either
> 90, 180, or 270 degrees. The page range is specified in the same
> format as with the `--pages` option, described below. Repeat the option
> to rotate multiple groups of pages. If the angle is preceded by `+` or `-`,
> it is added to or subtracted from the original rotation. Otherwise, the
> rotation angle is set explicitly to the given value.

### References:

1. `qpdf --help | less -RFX`
2. [This answer by @Royi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495660/114401)
3. [QPDF](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) on GitHub
4. [Manual](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) of QPDF (more extensive than `man` page)

### Related

1. My answer: [How to extract PDF pages by page number or range of page numbers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf/1318201#1318201)

Comment: And has proper cmdline syntax: `--rotate` not `-rotate`.

Comment: What's more: `--rotate=90` not `-rotate 90`.

Comment: To rotate a single file in place: `qpdf --rotate=90 --replace-input in.pdf`.

Comment: Best answer out of all the solutions. Some of the other packages are 200MB to install!

Comment: I also liked it very much.

Answer (score 19):

**pdftk** is no longer available on Ubuntu 18.04 due to some deprecated dependencies.

The best solution I found was the (graphical) tool <del>pdfshuffler</del> **pdfarranger***.

Install (see the installation steps in https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger) and run it. Open the desired PDF file, select the files to rotate and then click the rotate button in the header bar (or use the right click menu). It can also concatenate PDFs and some other nice things.

* pdfarranger is a fork of the abandoned (?) pdfshuffler

Comment: Do you have to rotate each page manually? That's a deal breaker. I need to rotate a hundreds-page-long PDF book to view it better (larger) on a Kindle. *UPDATE*: Just tried it, nope, you can Ctrl-A to select all pages then rotate them all in one step.

Comment: `sudo snap install pdftk` works just fine on Ubuntu 18.04. There is more usage info in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/569337/236230).

Comment: pdfshuffler has been renamed to pdfarranger, and it indeed is great

Comment: pdftk is back in the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 20.04 and later.

Answer (score 8):

To improve output resolution (default is 72 DPI), I got good results with:

```
convert -rotate -90 -density 200 input.pdf output.pdf
```

This was for a .pdf of a scanned document. I found that `-density 300` reduced quality somewhat versus `-density 200`.

Comment: Adding -density 300, 600 and even 1200 had only slight improvement on output quality.

Comment: As noted in the other answer suggesting `convert`, this is inherently a lossy operation.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to print a large PDF file (200+ pages) as a grouping of signatures for bookbinding.

- I used `pdfjam` to make the signature sets:

  ```
  pdfjam --landscape --signature 16 filename.pdf
  ```
- I opened the new `pdfjam` file in a viewer and printed odd pages.
- I put the stack of printed pages back into the printer flipped around,
  then printed even pages.

I now have a perfect set of signatures for binding. `pdfjam` flips the odd pages upside down and would need to be rotated 180 if you use the duplexer on your printer. Flip the pages manually after printing the odds and there is no need to rotate them electronically. I also found `pdfsam` to be a very useful tool for batching edits to PDF files.

Just hoping this manual flip might save someone some time.

Answer (score 2):

Although it does have its limitations, I quite often use PDFedit, especially for the rotation of PDF scans. While ImageMagick's convert (using rather high -density values) achieves quite a good quality, it also bloats the file (original: 155 kiB, 180° rotated copy: 1.2 MiB). PDFedit rotates the same image with unchanged quality without noticably changing the file size.

Comment: sounds very promising! i also noticed the issue with changing the file size drastically that you refer to.

Answer (score 2):

I use this command to automatically rotate pdf files to become upright down if they aren't upright in the first place :

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/All -sOutputFile="$outputFile" "$file"
```

Comment: This had zero effect.

Comment: @Colin'tHart My command only restores the document to become upright down if it wasn't upright in the first place, to force the rotation use `pdf90` or `pdf180` or `pdf270` instead, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459596/135038)

Comment: This worked for me. I guess it may work for some PDF documents not for others.