# Remove page or page range from pdf with qpdf

Tags: pdf

I've been growing fond of [qpdf's simplicity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394065/command-line-how-do-you-rotate-a-pdf-file-90-degrees/634882#634882) and speed.

Is there a way to use qpdf to remove a page or page range from a pdf document using qpdf?

Say I want to remove pg 2.
Say I want to remove pg 4-7.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can remove pages using qpdf.

`qpdf input.pdf --pages . 1,3-r1 -- output.pdf` should remove only the second page.

`qpdf input.pdf --pages . 1-3,8-r1 -- output.pdf` should remove pages 4-7, inclusively, from the input pdf.

The `r1` in the page range specifies a number of pages from the end of the document.  See [page-ranges](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#page-ranges) for more information.

Of course, page selection is more powerful than simply having the ability to remove pages from a document (what I use it most for).  Page selection allows merging different ranges from different PDFs as well.  See [page-selection](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#page-selection).

See https://askubuntu.com/a/672001.